# Protractor TAB key has stopped changing focus and is now adding spaces

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

We have some protractor tests that uses the TAB key to change focus to the next input field, and it was working great.

Somewhere in the last days it has stopped changing focus and is now adding spaces instead.

- manually, pressing TAB workers.
- we also tested google.com and it behaves the same.

Did anyone encounter this change of behaviour?

Thanks!

```
    var tab = protractor.Key.TAB;

    describe('testing', function() {
      it('Should do stuff.', function() {
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true; // for non angular page.

        browser.get('http://www.google.com');
        browser.sleep(1000);
        $('.gsfi').sendKeys('123');
        browser.sleep(1000); // have some time to look.
        browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.TAB).perform(); //different methods, same effect.
        $('.gsfi').sendKeys(tab); // different methods, same effect.
      });
    });
```

Comment: Is it reproducible on both Chrome and Firefox? Thanks.

Comment: Happens only in Chrome.

Comment: Related issue: https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2370

Comment: Why do you need to tab through the elements, when you can just send keys directly to the element you want to interact with without needing to change focus?

Comment: Hi Sirk, by tabbing through the app we assure it's keyboard accessibility.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to be a regression in Chrome 44. I've already pointed on [an issue in *Protractor* bug tracker](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2370) in comments. [Here is an issue in *chromedriver* bug tracker](https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1159), which describes the same behavior. In some cases not only TAB, but also ENTER and SPACE keys started failing.

Reading comments of these issues brings to a conclusion that there were changes in Chromium sources in how input events are being handled ([possible breaking diff](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/e20f50c297917306f1f438a58ae29e94fb7bc912%5E%21/#F0)).

There is [an issue in *Chromium* bug tracker](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=513768) aboit it, developers say that it has already been fixed, but it will take some time to get this fix into stable release of Chrome. If you are in a hurry, you should downgrade Chrome to a version **below** 44.0.2358.0 ([source](https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1159#c5)).

**Update:**

I've recently got an update and TAB key is working again in Chrome 44.0.2403.130.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably the reason why we have now a bunch of failing tests that use shortcuts like COMMAND+W, COMMAND+T etc. Thanks!